# Differentiation of logarithmic functions .

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx9kC.jpg

If $ y = \log_{10} x + \log_e 10 + \log_x x + \log_{10} 10$, then find $\frac{dy}{dx} $

So I was doing this question and I got my answer as $\frac{1}{x \ln 10} + \frac{1}{10}$

Where as in the book the answer was given as $\frac{1}{x \ln 10}$ only . I strongly believe that my answer is right , but I may be wrong.

Can somebody please help me clarify my doubt.
Regards

Also can somebody please embed the photo as I am currently unable to do so from my device.

Comment: I believe the book; what is $\log_X X$?

Answer (score 1):

$y = \log_{10} x + \log_e 10 + \log_x x + \log_{10} 10 \implies y = \frac{\log_e x}{\log_e 10} + \log_e 10 + \frac{\log_e x}{\log_e x} + \frac{\log_e 10}{\log_e 10} \implies y =\frac{\log_e x}{\log_e 10} + \log_e 10 + 1 + \frac{\log_e 10}{\log_e 10}  $

Now $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{x \log_e 10} $